# TableView don't show when script is running PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to load data from the data frame to a table view.
Then I wanted to show it on my TableView UI.

But I randomly get a : QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

I got no QPainter object so I could not end it.

EDIT : Sometimes it happens when I scroll the TableView
dataframe_orders is a dataframe i extracted from my database.
And check order passed is just a function to update something on the db.
They are working correctly on another code where i used tkinter.
I tried to destroy table view object and model when i leave the window (it's a secondary window so to be back to the main window)

I added the PandasModel which is basically the model i use to set my dataframe on the tableview

Here is my code :

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df.copy()

    def toDataFrame(self):
        return self._df.copy()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

class Ui_OrderWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, OrderWindow):
        OrderWindow.setObjectName("OrderWindow")
        OrderWindow.resize(1919, 600)
        self.centralwidgetorders = QtWidgets.QWidget(OrderWindow)
        self.centralwidgetorders.setObjectName("centralwidgetorders")
        self.fenetreorders = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidgetorders)
        self.fenetreorders.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1891, 551))
        self.fenetreorders.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"border-radius:20px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.fenetreorders.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.fenetreorders.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.fenetreorders.setObjectName("fenetreorders")
        self.titreorders = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.fenetreorders)
        self.titreorders.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 50, 151, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Dubai")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.titreorders.setFont(font)
        self.titreorders.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(18, 0, 124)")
        self.titreorders.setObjectName("titreorders")
        self.generatemailorders = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.fenetreorders)
        self.generatemailorders.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 500, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Dubai")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.generatemailorders.setFont(font)
        self.generatemailorders.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"background-color:  rgb(18, 0, 124);\n"
"color: rgb(239, 239, 239);\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color:rgb(21, 0, 166);\n"
"color: rgb(239, 239, 239);\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"\n"
"}")
        self.generatemailorders.setObjectName("generatemailorders")
        self.tableVieworders = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.fenetreorders)
        self.tableVieworders.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 1851, 371))
        self.tableVieworders.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);\n"
"border-radius:0px;\n"
"")
        self.tableVieworders.setObjectName("tableVieworders")
        self.btnretour = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.fenetreorders)
        self.btnretour.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 41, 41))
        self.btnretour.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {    \n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: transparent;\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"     border: none;\n"
"    border-radius:0px;\n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.482759, y1:0, x2:0.517241, y2:0.977273, stop:0 rgba(238, 238, 238, 255), stop:1 rgba(238, 238, 238, 255))\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btnretour.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("left-arrow-icon-7.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnretour.setIcon(icon)
        self.btnretour.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.btnretour.setObjectName("btnretour")
        self.titlezone = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidgetorders)
        self.titlezone.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1891, 41))
        self.titlezone.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(18, 0, 124);\n"
"border-top-left-radius:20px;\n"
"border-top-right-radius:20px;")
        self.titlezone.setObjectName("titlezone")
        self.titlewindow = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.titlezone)
        self.titlewindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 101, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Dubai")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.titlewindow.setFont(font)
        self.titlewindow.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(239, 239, 239);")
        self.titlewindow.setObjectName("titlewindow")
        self.framebtn = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidgetorders)
        self.framebtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1790, 10, 101, 41))
        self.framebtn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(18, 0,124);\n"
"border-radius:20px;")
        self.framebtn.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.framebtn.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.framebtn.setObjectName("framebtn")
        self.btnminimize = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.framebtn)
        self.btnminimize.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 1, 40, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btnminimize.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btnminimize.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btnminimize.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 0))
        self.btnminimize.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 16777215))
        self.btnminimize.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {    \n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: transparent;\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"     border: none;\n"
"    border-radius:0px;\n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(16, 1, 108);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btnminimize.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("minimizeicon-removebg-preview.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnminimize.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btnminimize.setObjectName("btnminimize")
        self.btnclose = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.framebtn)
        self.btnclose.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 0, 40, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btnclose.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btnclose.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btnclose.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 0))
        self.btnclose.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 16777215))
        self.btnclose.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {    \n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: transparent;\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"     border: none;\n"
"    border-radius:0px;\n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(16, 1, 108);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btnclose.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("cil-x.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnclose.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btnclose.setObjectName("btnclose")
        OrderWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidgetorders)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(OrderWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        OrderWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(OrderWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(OrderWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, OrderWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        OrderWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("OrderWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.titreorders.setText(_translate("OrderWindow", "Orders Found"))
        self.generatemailorders.setText(_translate("OrderWindow", "Generate Mail"))
        self.titlewindow.setText(_translate("OrderWindow", "AutoTrade"))
        self.btnminimize.setToolTip(_translate("OrderWindow", "Minimize"))
        self.btnclose.setToolTip(_translate("OrderWindow", "Minimize"))
class OrderWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_OrderWindow()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # MINIMIZE
        self.ui.btnminimize.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())

        # CLOSE
        self.ui.btnclose.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close_order())

        self.model = PandasModel(dataframe_orders)
        self.ui.tableVieworders.setModel(self.model)
       
            self.ui.tableVieworders.show()
            print(self.ui.tableVieworders.__dict__)
            self.ui.generatemailorders.clicked.connect(lambda: self.runmailorders())


            self.ui.btnretour.clicked.connect(lambda: self.retour_main())
            def moveWindow(event):


                # IF LEFT CLICK MOVE WINDOW
                if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
                    self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos)
                    self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
                    event.accept()

            self.setFixedSize(self.size())
            print(vars(self.ui.tableVieworders))

            ## SHOW ==> MAIN WINDOW
            ########################################################################
            self.show()


    def retour_main(self):
        del self.model
        self.ui.tableVieworders.destroy()
        MainWindow()
        self.destroy()

    def close_order(self):
        del self.model
        self.ui.tableVieworders.destroy()
        MainWindow()
        self.destroy()

    def runmailorders(self):
        check_order_passe()
        del self.model
        self.ui.tableVieworders.destroy()
        self.close()
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: that's hard to provide because it happens randomly sometimes data load correctly sometimes i got this error. That's why i'm lost and I thought i forgot to close something but ... I really don't know why it happen

Sometimes it happens when I Scroll the TableView

Comment: with the minimal code you provided is almost impossible to help you. I suggest you to try to slowly reduce the code while you can ensure that the issue still happens, and add more verbose logging. Also, avoid event handling "monkey patching" like you did with `mouseMoveEvent` as it often leads to bugs difficult to track down. Finally, if you're not already doing it, run the code in a terminal/prompt, as some errors are often ignored when using an IDE.

Comment: provided more code so you can see the UI also. I am running from terminal yup and I will try to delete this function. Do you know how can I make something like mouse Move Event better ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Even without this function the error is still happening

Comment: Okay it seems to work better without the function runned the wrong version.
Do you know how can I make the moveWindow event better ?

Comment: Unfortunately your example is still **not** reproducible: what are PandasModel, dataframe_orders, MainWindow, check_order_passe? And why do you continuously call "destroy" (which is not a good way to remove a widget)? And why do you call destroy the table and then try set a model on it afterwards? Also, you shouldn't `del` a model that is set on an item view: doing it could even cause a crash. I'm sorry but your code seems to have lots of issues to begin with, and since it's also not reproducible, it's really impossible to help you at this point.